# Drawing on windows with 32-bit color depth

Tags: x11

For some reason, I'm not able to draw at all on a X11 window with a depth of 32 in my reparenting WM. I've tried using Xft for drawing text, drawing rectangles, the inbuilt functionality for drawing text... nothing shows up on depth 32 windows. This is how I draw the window, using the X11rb library:

```rs
let win_aux = xproto::CreateWindowAux::new()
            .event_mask(
                xproto::EventMask::EXPOSURE
                    | xproto::EventMask::SUBSTRUCTURE_REDIRECT
                    | xproto::EventMask::SUBSTRUCTURE_NOTIFY
                    | xproto::EventMask::BUTTON_PRESS
                    | xproto::EventMask::BUTTON_RELEASE
                    | xproto::EventMask::POINTER_MOTION
                    | xproto::EventMask::ENTER_WINDOW
                    | xproto::EventMask::PROPERTY_CHANGE,
            )
            .background_pixel(self.config.background_pixel)
            .border_pixel(self.config.active_border_pixel)
            .colormap(attr.colormap);
        self.conn.create_window(
            geom.depth,
            frame_win,
            screen.root,
            geom.x,
            geom.y,
            geom.width,
            geom.height + self.config.title_height as u16,
            self.config.border_width as u16,
            xproto::WindowClass::INPUT_OUTPUT,
            attr.visual,
            &win_aux,
        )?;
        self.conn.grab_server()?.check()?;
        self.conn
            .change_save_set(xproto::SetMode::INSERT, ev.window)?
            .check()?;
        self.conn
            .reparent_window(ev.window, frame_win, 0, self.config.title_height as i16)?
            .check()?;
        self.conn.map_window(ev.window)?.check()?;
        self.conn.map_window(frame_win)?.check()?;
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: My suspicion is that the only thing different must be the unique draw, therefore it must be an issue w/ that.

Comment: It looks like this happens whether or not you use Xft; the issue is just drawing to the 32-bit window in general.

Comment: How do you draw to the window? I think core protocol should always end up using an alpha of zero, so "bunches holes" into your window. You could try setting your background pixel to something "visible" (`0xffff0000` or whatever) and check if your drawing then "punches holes" into that.

Comment: Also: Your code example shows Rust code using x11rb. Your question says you use Xft (AFAIK this library only works with Xlib), and your tags say you are using xcb. What are you using?

Comment: Originally, I was using Xft and interfacing with xlib for it. Later I realized that no drawing primitive worked on the frame windows, so I edited the question to make it more generic. My background color does have an alpha of FF, but I will try using that color too. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, using red makes no difference.

Comment: One way I tried is drawing with image_text8.

Comment: https://github.com/codic12/worm/tree/a07871d35cf037e55ad83d851738b934febc05ee Here is a permanent link which shows how I tried drawing with xft.

Comment: You might be interested in using x11rb's `atom_manager!` macro (I just came by `src/ipc.rs` and `src/ewmh.rs`): https://docs.rs/x11rb/0.9.0/x11rb/macro.atom_manager.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that should simplify those.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't fully figured out what is going on, but I ran your code under [`xtrace`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/xtrace) and found this:

```
000:<:005c: 20: RENDER-Request(139,4): CreatePicture pid=0x00200001 drawable=0x00200002 format=0x00000029 values={}
000:<:005d: 16: Request(53): CreatePixmap depth=0x20 pid=0x00200003 drawable=0x0000051f width=1 height=1
000:<:005e: 24: RENDER-Request(139,4): CreatePicture pid=0x00200004 drawable=0x00200003 format=0x00000025 values={repeat=true(0x01)}
000:<:005f:  8: Request(54): FreePixmap drawable=0x00200003
000:>:005c:Error 8=Match: major=139, minor=4, bad=0x00000029, seq=005c
```

So, something you are doing causes an Error. I guess this then also explains the missing drawing.

So, my first suggestion is to not silently ignore errors:

```
diff --git a/src/wm.rs b/src/wm.rs
index 68e43f5..bc95d20 100644
--- a/src/wm.rs
+++ b/src/wm.rs
@@ -240,7 +240,10 @@ where
             let ev = match self.conn.wait_for_event() {
                 Ok(ev) => ev,
 
-                Err(_) => continue,
+                Err(e) => {
+                    eprintln!("Error: {:?}", e);
+                    continue;
+                }
             };
             let _ = self.dispatch_event(&ev);
         }
@@ -293,6 +296,7 @@ where
             protocol::Event::DestroyNotify(ev) => self.handle_destroy_notify(ev)?,
             protocol::Event::ClientMessage(ev) => self.handle_client_message(ev)?,
             protocol::Event::ConfigureNotify(ev) => self.handle_configure_notify(ev)?,
+            protocol::Event::Error(ev) => eprintln!("X11 error: {:?}", ev),
             _ => {}
         }
         Ok(())
```

(Only the second change is necessary here, but I came across the first one first and only later figured out that I was wrong.)

I am not quite sure what the second problem is, but I would guess that it is the following code:

```rust
xft::XftDrawCreate(
    self.xlib_conn,
    frame_win.into(),
    xlib::XDefaultVisual(self.xlib_conn, 0),
    xlib::XDefaultColormap(self.xlib_conn, 0),
)
```

Here, you are telling xft that your frame window uses the screen's default visual and colormap. However, for depth=32 windows, this cannot be true (and I checked - your frame window is also depth=32 in this case).

So... you somehow have to give the right visual to Xft and colormap to Xft. Apparently, you use a `GetWindowAttributes` request to create your frame window with the same values as the contained client window.

So, now you'll somehow have to translate this visual XID to a Xlib `Visual*` pointer, which sounds like some hairy code....

Comment: Thanks. I tried it like this: https://hastebin.com/rowulorojo.rust ; changing the colormap does not change a thing, but if I change the visual and colormap then it can't draw on anything, even if window depth is not 32.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it like this: https://hastebin.com/rowulorojo.rust ; changing the colormap does not change a thing, but if I change the visual and colormap then it can't draw on anything, even if window depth is not 32. If I compare the return value of XDefaultScreen and my custom-constructed one, the only difference is the visual id, as expected. So, using the visual doesn't fix the problem, it makes it worse. Interesting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69693078/creating-subwindow-fails-with-badregion/69693787 I tried creating a subwindow on frame and got that to render fine. However if I draw something in *that*, it still doesn't work on depth 32 windows (but the bg renders).