# Creating subwindow fails with BadRegion?

Tags: rust, x11

In trying to fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/69647995?noredirect=1, I had an idea; what if I drew the things (that were failing to draw directly on the window) in subwindows of the frame window? It looks like other WMs like Openbox also took this approach.

So I tried doing this:

```rs
 let text_win = self.conn.generate_id()?;
        let text_win_aux = xproto::CreateWindowAux::new()
            .event_mask(
                xproto::EventMask::EXPOSURE
                    | xproto::EventMask::SUBSTRUCTURE_REDIRECT
                    | xproto::EventMask::SUBSTRUCTURE_NOTIFY
                    | xproto::EventMask::BUTTON_PRESS
                    | xproto::EventMask::BUTTON_RELEASE
                    | xproto::EventMask::POINTER_MOTION
                    | xproto::EventMask::ENTER_WINDOW
                    | xproto::EventMask::PROPERTY_CHANGE,
            )
            .background_pixel(0xFFFFFF);
        self.conn.create_window(
            COPY_DEPTH_FROM_PARENT,
            text_win,
            frame_win,
            15,
            15,
            60,
            25,
            0,
            xproto::WindowClass::INPUT_OUTPUT,
            screen.root_visual,
            &text_win_aux,
        )?;
        self.conn.map_window(text_win)?
```

But it doesn't work (there is no white rectangle rendered), and it looks like I get a BadRegion error too.
What I expect is that a white rectangle is rendered on the frame window (as the background_pixel of the child is white, and I map it to the frame).
What could I be doing wrong? This doesn't seem to be affected by depth, btw.

Comment: Include the complete question in the question itself (don't leave part of the description in the link)

Comment: Also change "doesn't work" to "do nothing" if that's what you mean.

Comment: And which language is this? Looks somewhat like C# or something

Comment: The language is Rust.  Why should I change "doesn't work" to "do nothing"? The code doesn't work as expected, so I think the terminology is perfectly fine. The complete question is here, the link was just saying why I tried this; but the question of the actual issue is all here.

Comment: Because "doesn't work" is very not-specific and does not help the answerer to diagnose the question. "a window popup and disappear immediately", "it shows the error message ABC", "it crashes the computer" are specific.

Comment: Also explain what you *want* the code to do.

Comment: I've clarified more, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. The "text_win" needs to be using the same visual as the frame window; I accidentally used the X11 screen's root visual instead.

So this create_window call functions as expected:

```rs
    .background_pixel(0xFFFFFF);
        self.conn.create_window(
            COPY_DEPTH_FROM_PARENT,
            text_win,
            frame_win,
            15,
            15,
            60,
            25,
            0,
            xproto::WindowClass::INPUT_OUTPUT,
            attr.visual,
            &text_win_aux,
        )?;
```

(Also, I discovered that the BadRegion was something else, it was a xcompmgr bug, nothing related to this)